# R programming: save three dimensional outputs after loop

Tags: r, list, loops, save, dataframe

I am new to R and I would like to save the out puts after the loop

```
 for (i in 1:5) {
    for (d in 1:10) {
     fonction1
     fonction2
     fonction3
   }
  }
```

At the end I would like to have 1 list-> contains 5 list-> contains 1*10 data frame -> contains certain number*3 numeric data. (I dont know if im saying it correctly, what i want to have is: like in Matlab, there is a 1*5 structure -> contains five 1*10 structure -> contain certain number*3 numeric data).

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to create a list. i.e. `lst <- vector('list', 5)` and then assign the output to the `lst[[i]]`  Without a reproducible example, it is not easy to help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking after something like the following:

```
out <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
    outList <- list()
    for (d in 1:10) {
     outVect <- c()
     outVect[1] <- fonction1()
     outVect[2] <- fonction2()
     outVect[3] <- fonction3()
     outList[[d]] <- outVect
   }
   out[[i]] <- outList
  }
```

Then you can look at:

```
str(out)
```

to see the structure of your answer

Comment: Great. Remember to flag the answer to your problem as the one you selected by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that people see your issue is solved. And if you like an answer you can always click on the up arrow to give it credit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
  lapply(1:10, function(d) {
    data.frame(function1(),
               function2(),
               function3())
  })
})
```

Assuming `function1`, `function2` and `function3` all return equal-length vectors, the above code should produce your desired object. You can use `i` and `d` identically as you would have used them in your `for` loop code.